# ]Incorrect syntax near '_283846_2019'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Tags: python, sql-server

I have to connect the sql database to python so that I can add new user data via python.

I have tried the int conversion which puts me in further trouble of null types dataset. 
i have tried the bracket placement. It doesn't work.

```
import os
import datetime
import pyodbc
import sqlite3


file_open = open("filenames.txt","r")

path = 'C:\\Users\\Timble\\Desktop\\Face_recognition\\user-id_filenames\\'
flag_loc = 1
flag_proc = 0
flag_vis = 0
file_read_lines = file_open.readlines()
for line in file_read_lines:
    for character in line:
        if character == "_":
            details = line.split("_")
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            name = line
            print("name:", name)                                                    #col-3
            print("type of name:", type(name))
            user_id = int(details[1])
            print("user_id:", details[1])                                             #col-2
            print("type of user_id:", type(user_id))
            date = details[2]
            print("date on which photo is taken:", details[2])                           #col-4
            print("type of data:",type(details[2]))
            now = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            print("Current date and time: ", now)                                 #col-6
            print("type of current date:", type(now))
            path2 = path + details[1]
            if os.path.exists(path2):
                print(path2)
            else:
                os.makedirs(path2)
            #break
            date = str(date)
            print("type of date", type(date))
            user_id = str(user_id)
            print("type of user_id", type(user_id))
            name = str(name)
            print("type of name",type(name))
            now = str(now)
            print("type of now", type(now))
            flag_loc = str(flag_loc)
            print("type loc flag", type(flag_loc))
            flag_proc = str(flag_proc)
            print("type proc flag", type(flag_proc))
            flag_vis = str(flag_vis)
            print("type vis flag", type(flag_vis))
            conn = pyodbc.connect(
                 "DRIVER={SQl Server};"
                 "server=DESKTOP-3ORBD3I\MSSQL;"
                 "database=TimbleSecuritySystem;"
                 "uid=sa;"
                 "pwd=P@ssword")
            cur = conn.cursor()
            sqlInsertUser = "Insert Into retraining (date, user_id, image_name,location_flagged, processing_flagged, insert_date, visible)Values( "+ date + " , " + user_id + " , " + name + " , " + flag_loc + " , " + flag_proc + " , " + now + " , " + flag_vis + " )"
            print(sqlInsertUser)
            cur.execute(sqlInsertUser)
            conn.commit()
            break
file_open.close()
```

The actual results tell me that print(sqlInsertUser) prints all the right values.
I am expecting the execute command to work and sql data added there.

Comment: What is the output at the line 'print(sqlInsertUser)'?

Comment: Don't use string concatenation or formatting on SQL queries. It lead to error like the one you are observing and SQL injection vulnerabilities. Use the `parameters` feature of the `execute()` method instead. See the [docs](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executesql-parameters) of your DB adapter for details.

Answer (score 1):

This line is the problem:

```
 sqlInsertUser = "Insert Into retraining (date, user_id, image_name,location_flagged, processing_flagged, insert_date, visible)Values( "+ date + " , " + user_id + " , " + name + " , " + flag_loc + " , " + flag_proc + " , " + now + " , " + flag_vis + " )"
```

For example if `name` contains some invalid characters e.g. "[" or "]", then the `execute` call fails because the `name` string is not properly enclosed. (It should be enclosed in a pair of quote)

You can use the parameter substitution support in pyodbc e.g.

```
 sqlInsertUser = "Insert Into retraining (date, user_id, 
     image_name, location_flagged, processing_flagged, insert_date, 
     visible) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```

then run

```
cur.execute(sqlInsertUser, date, user_id, name, flag_loc, flag_proc, now, flag_vis)
```

(My sample code above is untested. You might need to fix some syntax errors)

For  more details about the syntax see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle or https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor